# Why does Top Reviewers of First Post alway have a score of 20?

Tags: support, review-queues

I got the privilege to review some time ago. When browsing the review history of **First post** I always see the same people (especially [Soner Gönül](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-g%C3%B6n%C3%BCl)) with a score of 20 and not higher.

Is this a bug or a limit?

Comment: (not answering your question, but additionally:) Not sure about generally, but right now all users on 20 are sorted by ascending userid, which is probably why once the list is filled with all 20s you tend to see the same top reviewers. (that might not be exactly how they're sorted but there is definitely a pattern as to who get the top spots)

Comment: Yeah, those guys can be annoying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Users are limited to reviewing 20 posts per queue each UTC day, unless the queue has more than 1,000 items in it, in which case the limit bumps up to 40.