# Why is the Close Votes queue limited to only 40 reviews per day, when it has 11K questions waiting to be reviewed?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, vote-to-close

Two questions basically.

1. How come the Close Votes queue came to be 11K?
2. Why is there still a limit of 40 when there are so many waiting?

I've read [Why is there a limit on close votes in a day?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271795/why-is-there-a-limit-on-close-votes-in-a-day) and understood it but can't the limit be changed to say 100 for 'close votes' seeing how many there are?

Comment: ["There's about **165,000** questions with 1, 2, 3, or 4 close votes on them currently. There's about 11,000 questions that currently appear in the Close Votes queue..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278059/introducing-the-2014-end-of-the-year-close-vote-extravaganza)

Comment: ^^^ increasing from 40 to 100 won't help

Comment: @gnat Maybe I misunderstood but the link you sent says 500 a day limit was given on a certain day, if 500 a day is useful for a day, why isn't 100 a day useless?

Comment: You did see [this comment from @animuson](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278059/introducing-the-2014-end-of-the-year-close-vote-extravaganza#comment122767_278059)?

Comment: Not every question has an urgent need to be closed. You don't need to worry about them.

Comment: Similarly, not every question needs to be closed at all. A high volume of questions in the close review doesn't indicate anything useful by itself.

Comment: I hate to agree with moderators but in this case, I am with @BoltClock - there's no urgency to close everything that is voted. FWIW there are ~20,000 users eligible to vote close; if all of them would use 40 votes, that would be enough to close or drop everything off the queue in just a day. If more close review power is needed, we better look for involving more users than giving few of them more votes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How come the 'close votes' review list came to be 11 K?

The Close Votes queue used to include every single question with at least 1 close vote on it. I think it may even have included questions that had no close votes on them, but a duplicate flag on it or a flag to close the question *(users with < 3k rep can only flag vote not close vote)*. There were rules though to age out questions from that queue though, but there was a decent period of time where the Close Votes queue did show over 80k questions.

The main reason it shows only about 11k questions in there now is because of this [status-completed feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions) by [Shog9 ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9).

> - Two parameters:
>
>   1. **FlagsAgeDaysThreshold**: the number of days old the newest vote or flag must be for a question to remain under review. Default value:
>        4
>   2. **FlagsThreshold**: the number of votes or flags required for a question to remain under review once FlagsAgeDaysThreshold has been
>        exceeded. Default value: 3.

Here's how the /review page looked on October 27th, 2013, as shown [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131027221438/https://stackoverflow.com/review).

[image]

> And why is there still a limit of 40 when there are so many waiting?

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266213/why-does-top-reviewers-of-first-post-alway-have-a-score-of-20/266214#266214) by [animuson ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) answers that question :

> Users are limited to reviewing 20 posts per queue each UTC day, unless the queue has more than 1,000 items in it, in which case the limit bumps up to 40.

I would propose/feature-request that there should be another rule too. If the queue has more than 5000 items in it you should get 80 reviews per day. If the queue has more than 10,000 items in it, you should get 100 reviews per day. And I'd request the max closes votes per day that a user should currently receive on SO should be 100, not only 50. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

Your first question is answered and well [documented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions). I'll focus on the more interesting and as-yet unanswered question.

> Why is there still a limit of 40 when there are so many waiting?

The real answer is because regardless of if there are 100 or 1000 or 1000000 items in the queue, you as a person have limits. The more tasks you do, the less effective you get with them. The more likely it is to make mistakes, to just not care anymore, and to get complacent in your voting patterns.

Now, you personally might have more in you than the default amount of 20, or even more than the upgraded amount of 40. And in theory, when you reach your limit, you stop. But the reality is as humans, we keep going long past our limit of reliably performing the tasks.

This is the entire reason there's a maximum in the first place. It's why there's a reputation cap. It's why there's voting limits. It's why most of the constraints in the system exist: people should not feel pressured or compelled to perform any of the activities of the site, whether it's moderation or participation.

Comment: "... people should not feel pressured or compelled to perform any of the activities of the site, whether it's moderation or participation." By the same token, surely people who want to go above and beyond should be permitted to do so?

Comment: Ian, that's been debated before, but the consensus seems to be no, for a number of reasons. Typically those who would go ad infinitum are doing it more for the imaginary internet points than the good of the site, which leads to poor quality in the work they do. Second, people tend to not realize their limits and go beyond what they can hope to maintain a high quality standard.

Comment: There's a big difference between "above and beyond" and "ad infinitum". 100 votes instead of 40 votes is not infinite, and as you have already noted, different people have different limits. Furthermore, I'd expect that the system and the community would pick up on people who are no longer reliably performing tasks (e.g. by declining their close votes) and compensate accordingly.

Comment: But there isn't a difference, that's the point. You have to draw the line somewhere. That somewhere is going to be too high for some and too few for others, but it's better to be on the too few side to prevent quality degradation.