# Why are there so many pending close votes in Review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

Whenever I go to the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) I see thousands of Pending Close Votes for review while other queues are mostly 0 to a few hundred.

[image: Close Votes Review example]

- Why are so many of them pending?
- Is it normal for Stack Overflow?
- What can we do to handle those in a better way?

Personally I try to use filters (eg. TAG=android + duplicate) so that I can review as much as I can.

How can we contribute to make it better?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252586/regarding-the-stack-overflow-close-review-queue

Comment: Yes, this is normal for Stack Overflow. Sadly.

Comment: see also [Why is the Close Votes queue limited to only 40 reviews per day, when it has 11K questions waiting to be reviewed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278074/839601) and [Is using reputation to scale the number of close votes the best way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281818/165773)

Comment: There is dedicated [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to handle that queue ... you could blame them for slacking ...

Comment: We also use a chatbot named [Closey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4424245/closey) in order to tell us what tags to filter for, and keep track of our progress in the queue. (the bot is currently down for maintenance)