# Why does the max # of reviews in Low Quality Posts review queue bump to 40 without reaching the queue size 1k?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

As far I know from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266213/why-does-top-reviewers-of-first-post-alway-have-a-score-of-20/266214#266214) by [animuson ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) :

> Users are limited to reviewing 20 posts per queue each UTC day, unless
>   the queue has more than 1,000 items in it, in which case the limit
>   bumps up to 40.

But in [Low Quality Posts Review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats), I often see it bumping from 20 to 40 without reaching the queue size of 1,000 items.

It usually remains limited to 20 when the UTC day starts, and bumps to 40 later.

I do not know based on which criteria it bumps and it seemed to me that queue size is not the only issue here. Because, sometimes I noticed this bumping when review queue was 175, sometimes when it crossed 200.

Could you please clarify the matter?

Comment: Also, note that the queue might be larger than the number you see. Items which are reviewed by you, but for which the review is not completed, are not counted in the number you see.

Comment: *"the queue might be larger than the number you see. Items which are reviewed by you, but for which the review is not completed, are not counted in the number you see."* -- good point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science/320971#320971) linked by [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel) in the comments is up to date.

Since April 26, 2016, the LQ queue gives you 40 reviews per day if the size of the queue is above 200.

The month before that, we had 30 reviews a day, as an experiment.
Before that, we had 40 reviews a day if the queue size exceeded 1000 items, as per the answer by animuson linked in the question. That answer is no longer up to date.

Comment: I believe this change is applicable to many other or may be all review queues and not just `Low Quality Posts` queue. Yesterday I had got 40 items to review in `Help and Improvement` queue also. There was one more queue where I got 40 items to review but I don't remember clearly.

Comment: @RBT Yes, it now works this way for all queues: over 150 items means 40 reviews, in every review queue. Citation needed before I edit that into the answer itself.